# WCF Service to insert data to database in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I have created a WCF service and have a SQL database set up and I want to create a service which allows me to have data inserted into the database.

Here is my WCF service and the method I have used to do this:

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    [ServiceContract]
    interface IBookingsService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        bool InsertBooking(Booking obj);
    }

[DataContract]
public class Booking
{
    [DataMember]
    public int bk_BookingID;
    [DataMember]
    public string bk_StudentID;
    [DataMember]
   public string bk_Forename;
    [DataMember]
   public string bk_Surname;
    [DataMember]
    public string bk_EventID;
    [DataMember]
    public string bk_EventTitle;
    [DataMember]
    public string bk_EventDesc;
    [DataMember]
    public string bk_EventDate;
    [DataMember]
    public string bk_EventTime;
    [DataMember]
    public string bk_EventLocation;
}
```

svc

```
namespace WcfService1
{
    public class BookingsService1 : IBookingsService1
    {
        public bool InsertBooking(Booking obj)
        {
            bookingList.Add(obj);
            return true;
        }

       public static List<Booking> bookingList = new List<Booking>()
       {
            new Booking {bk_BookingID = 1, 
                              bk_StudentID = "11432857",
                              bk_Forename = "Mani",
                              bk_Surname = "Singh",
                              bk_EventTitle = "Bonk",
                              bk_EventDesc = "sdfsdfsd",
                              bk_EventDate = "11/11/14",
                              bk_EventTime = "21.30",
                              bk_EventLocation = "Forum"}
        };
    }

    public static class LinqUpdates
    {
        public static void Update<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
        {
            foreach (var item in source)
                action(item);
        }
    }
```

At the moment I am guessing when the service is used the data simply gets stored within the public class 'booking' but I want it to go into a table called 'BookingTable1'.

How can I implement this? Please help me as I have been trying to figure it out for quite a while now. Thank You.

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using (please update tags accordingly)....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation is not wrong. Use any database operation within your insert operation. For example use entity framework with wcf (ef creates tables as contracts or you can force that to do)

```
    public bool InsertBooking(Booking obj)
    {
        using(var db  = new Model1Entities())
        {
            db.Bookings.Attach(obj);
            db.Bookings.Add(obj);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return true; // or return obj
    }
```

Otherwise you can use any orm like that.

Comment: Hi there, when I type in the entity it does not come up and come up with the error 'Model1Entities' could not be found. Do I need to set up this Entity before hand? Also how so?